# Can't change static ip using network in centos8?

Tags: linux, centos, networkmanager

Change `IPADDR=192.168.1.120` to `IPADDR=192.168.1.121`

Then run:

```
systemctl restart NetworkManager
```

ip addr is still 192.168.1.120

if i run `systemctl restart network`,it works fine.

But network-scripts is deprecated in centos8.

Answer (score 1):

You should change that either in the frontend of your choice or with `nmcli`:

```
nmcli con mod name ipv4.addresses ip
```

(substitute `name` with the connection name and `ip` with the desired ip address.

For more documentation visit: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NetworkManager

Answer (score 1):

turning it off with:

`nmcli networking off`

then back on again with:

`nmcli networking on`

Or

`nmcli connection reload`

Or

`nmcli con down eth0`

`nmcli con up eth0`

Or you can use `nmtui`

`nmtui` is a text based user interface for controlling network manager, when we execute nmtui, it will open a text base user interface through which we can add, modify and delete connections.

Comment: None of these options are working for me. The new IP is correctly listed in the network-scripts file, but ip addr continues to show the old IP.  I've tried con up/down, connection reload, everything above.

Comment: Also tried setting the IP using `nmcli con mod name ipv4.addresses ip` to no avail.